# Can I use curly braces inside of a `\def`?

Tags: braces

I'm using tikz to compete in a codegolf question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110037/attack-decay-sustain-release/110054#110054).  To get around having to write `\typein` a whole bunch of times I have `\def~{\typein[}`.  Since nearly every `\typein` is prepended by `]{}` so I would like to define `]{}\typein[` instead.  However `\def` doesn't like curly braces for obvious reasons.

Is there some way I could add curly braces to my definition?

Here is my code if that helps at all:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz\def~{\typein[}~\a]{}~\s]{}~\d]{}~\r]{}\def\u{)--(\a+\d}\draw(0,0)--(\a,127\u,\s\u+64,\s\u+\r+64,0);\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem at all in using matching pairs of `{..}` which appears to be what you want. If I understand correctly your problem was hiding the `]` which needs to close the optional argument.

perhaps

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz\def~#1{\typein[#1]{}}~\a~\s~\d~\r\def\u{)--(\a+\d}\draw(0,0)--(\a,127\u,\s\u+64,\s\u+\r+64,0);\end{document}
```

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch not what you were trying to do but you asked about `{}` in a def which are no problem at all as shown here, and just vaguely hinted that you had tried to have the braces `[` and `]` for the optional `\typein` argument be in different macros, but that can not work.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was a bit confusing.  This does answer the question.  I was just commenting about how the provided code was helpful not the post as a whole.